# Can't open encrypted disk on new system?

Tags: arch-linux, encryption, luks, cryptsetup

I had a system running Arch Linux on an encrypted SSD using Btrfs and opened a secondary encrypted HDD on this system using a keyfile. The passphrase in the keyfile is also saved in my Keepass database as well as in an old keyfile on another system.
Now I installed Proxmox using XFS on the SSD and tried to open the encrypted HDD using the passphrase running the following command:

`# cryptsetup open /dev/sdX1 $mapper-name`

This returned "*No key available for this passphrase.*"

What is wrong? The passphrase is definitely valid. I also tried booting from a Manjaro Live system, but got the same error.

I might have followed the following tutorial to update my LUKS header, but I'm not sure.
https://mjg59.dreamwidth.org/66429.html

Also another disk can be unlocked easily on the same system.

I'll will attach more information about the LUKS header in a second.

EDIT:

```
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen --debug /dev/sdb1 disk                                                                                         
# cryptsetup 2.6.1 processing "cryptsetup luksOpen --debug /dev/sdb1 disk"
# Verifying parameters for command open.
# Running command open.
# Installing SIGINT/SIGTERM handler.
# Unblocking interruption on signal.
# Allocating context for crypt device /dev/sdb1.
# Trying to open and read device /dev/sdb1 with direct-io.
# Initialising device-mapper backend library.
# Trying to load any crypt type from device /dev/sdb1.
# Crypto backend (OpenSSL 3.1.1 30 May 2023 [default][legacy]) initialized in cryptsetup library version 2.6.1.
# Detected kernel Linux 6.1.30-1-MANJARO x86_64.
# Loading LUKS2 header (repair disabled).
# Acquiring read lock for device /dev/sdb1.
# Opening lock resource file /run/cryptsetup/L_8:17
# Verifying lock handle for /dev/sdb1.
# Device /dev/sdb1 READ lock taken.
# Trying to read primary LUKS2 header at offset 0x0.
# Opening locked device /dev/sdb1
# Verifying locked device handle (bdev)
# LUKS2 header version 2 of size 16384 bytes, checksum sha256.
# Checksum:e5cfc6dda22398807501ba54430599cad64b8d69c370427636e4da9d4b5695fb (on-disk)
# Checksum:e5cfc6dda22398807501ba54430599cad64b8d69c370427636e4da9d4b5695fb (in-memory)
# Trying to read secondary LUKS2 header at offset 0x4000.
# Reusing open ro fd on device /dev/sdb1
# LUKS2 header version 2 of size 16384 bytes, checksum sha256.
# Checksum:913b9d0d992b2b39071b1f6d6a82e4b6e8efcb27017e0be770eaea656c916fa1 (on-disk)
# Checksum:913b9d0d992b2b39071b1f6d6a82e4b6e8efcb27017e0be770eaea656c916fa1 (in-memory)
# Device size 4000785104896, offset 16777216.
# Device /dev/sdb1 READ lock released.
# PBKDF argon2id, time_ms 2000 (iterations 0), max_memory_kb 1048576, parallel_threads 4.
# Activating volume disk using token (any type) -1.
# dm version   [ opencount flush ]   [16384] (*1)
# dm versions   [ opencount flush ]   [16384] (*1)
# Detected dm-ioctl version 4.47.0.
# Detected dm-crypt version 1.24.0.
# Device-mapper backend running with UDEV support enabled.
# dm status disk  [ opencount noflush ]   [16384] (*1)
No usable token is available.
# Interactive passphrase entry requested.
Enter passphrase for /dev/sdb1: 
# Activating volume disk [keyslot -1] using passphrase.
# dm versions   [ opencount flush ]   [16384] (*1)
# dm status disk  [ opencount noflush ]   [16384] (*1)
# Keyslot 0 priority 1 != 2 (required), skipped.
# Trying to open LUKS2 keyslot 0.
# Running keyslot key derivation.
# Reading keyslot area [0x8000].
# Acquiring read lock for device /dev/sdb1.
# Opening lock resource file /run/cryptsetup/L_8:17
# Verifying lock handle for /dev/sdb1.
# Device /dev/sdb1 READ lock taken.
# Reusing open ro fd on device /dev/sdb1
# Device /dev/sdb1 READ lock released.
# Verifying key from keyslot 0, digest 0.
# Digest 0 (pbkdf2) verify failed with -1.
No key available with this passphrase.
# Interactive passphrase entry requested.
Enter passphrase for /dev/sdb1: 
# Activating volume disk [keyslot -1] using passphrase.
# dm versions   [ opencount flush ]   [16384] (*1)
# dm status disk  [ opencount noflush ]   [16384] (*1)
# Keyslot 0 priority 1 != 2 (required), skipped.
# Trying to open LUKS2 keyslot 0.
# Running keyslot key derivation.
# Reading keyslot area [0x8000].
# Acquiring read lock for device /dev/sdb1.
# Opening lock resource file /run/cryptsetup/L_8:17
# Verifying lock handle for /dev/sdb1.
# Device /dev/sdb1 READ lock taken.
# Reusing open ro fd on device /dev/sdb1
# Device /dev/sdb1 READ lock released.
# Verifying key from keyslot 0, digest 0.
# Digest 0 (pbkdf2) verify failed with -1.
No key available with this passphrase.
# Interactive passphrase entry requested.
Enter passphrase for /dev/sdb1: 
# Activating volume disk [keyslot -1] using passphrase.
# dm versions   [ opencount flush ]   [16384] (*1)
# dm status disk  [ opencount noflush ]   [16384] (*1)
# Keyslot 0 priority 1 != 2 (required), skipped.
# Trying to open LUKS2 keyslot 0.
# Running keyslot key derivation.
# Reading keyslot area [0x8000].
# Acquiring read lock for device /dev/sdb1.
# Opening lock resource file /run/cryptsetup/L_8:17
# Verifying lock handle for /dev/sdb1.
# Device /dev/sdb1 READ lock taken.
# Reusing open ro fd on device /dev/sdb1
# Device /dev/sdb1 READ lock released.
# Verifying key from keyslot 0, digest 0.
# Digest 0 (pbkdf2) verify failed with -1.
No key available with this passphrase.
# Releasing crypt device /dev/sdb1 context.
# Releasing device-mapper backend.
# Closing read only fd for /dev/sdb1.
Command failed with code -2 (no permission or bad passphrase).
```

And..

```
sudo cryptsetup luksDump /dev/sdb1                                                                                                          
LUKS header information
Version:        2
Epoch:          3
Metadata area:  16384 [bytes]
Keyslots area:  16744448 [bytes]
UUID:           276a0c49-344d-452b-98e0-9aaad8cc93f5
Label:          (no label)
Subsystem:      (no subsystem)
Flags:          (no flags)

Data segments:
  0: crypt
        offset: 16777216 [bytes]
        length: (whole device)
        cipher: aes-xts-plain64
        sector: 4096 [bytes]

Keyslots:
  0: luks2
        Key:        512 bits
        Priority:   normal
        Cipher:     aes-xts-plain64
        Cipher key: 512 bits
        PBKDF:      argon2id
        Time cost:  10
        Memory:     1048576
        Threads:    4
        Salt:       0b 00 e6 b8 0d dd 0c 4f 14 e6 33 84 02 83 ba 12 
                    66 40 4f 6d 15 65 f2 e0 c2 23 ef 73 03 0f af ac 
        AF stripes: 4000
        AF hash:    sha256
        Area offset:32768 [bytes]
        Area length:258048 [bytes]
        Digest ID:  0
Tokens:
Digests:
  0: pbkdf2
        Hash:       sha256
        Iterations: 275072
        Salt:       c0 b8 a4 2b e0 c0 f6 db 1f b5 c1 26 9b 8e 90 4f 
                    7e 5f fc 40 e6 89 0e 00 92 21 d9 c2 b1 f9 91 f9 
        Digest:     43 58 b1 65 ba a3 84 0e bf 3b d5 06 e1 38 d9 47 
                    2a 7f fa 00 52 75 07 69 e9 77 10 e3 a8 d5 a5 77
```